# Room database update creates unexpected UI side effects

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

When I simply Insert my data for the first time, all is well and when I reload my tiles, they get saved in the database and the tiles reload normally - see Animation 1.

[image]

When I try to update my tiles, I have this weird behaviour, like a loop - see Animation 2.

[image]

I am wondering what could be causing this. Here is my code:

```
@Entity (tableName = "saved_values_table")
data class SavedValues (
    @PrimaryKey()
    var index: Int,
    var visible: Boolean,
    var enabled: Boolean,
    var boardLetters: String,
    var boardLettersValue: Int
)
```

Dao:

```
 @Update
    suspend fun updateValues(values: SavedValues)
```

Repo:

```
suspend fun updateValues(savedValues: SavedValues) {
    savedValuesDao.updateValues(savedValues)
}
```

ViewModel:

```
   fun saveValues(index: Int, boardLetters: Array<Letter>) {
        val savedValues = readAllValues.value
        if (savedValues != null) {
            if (savedValues.isEmpty()) {
                addValues(
                    SavedValues(
                        index,
                        visible = true,
                        enabled = true,
                        boardLetters = boardLetters[index].name,
                        boardLettersValue = boardLetters[index].value
                    )
                )
            }
            else {
                updateValues(
                    SavedValues(
                        index,
                        visible = true,
                        enabled = true,
                        boardLetters = boardLetters[index].name,
                        boardLettersValue = boardLetters[index].value
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**
I am adding some more code here as the problem persists, contrary to what I said in my comment.

My whole Dao:

```
@Dao
interface SavedValuesDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun addValues(values: SavedValues)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM saved_values_table")
    fun readAllValues(): LiveData<List<SavedValues>>

    @Query("SELECT boardLetters FROM saved_values_table")
    fun readBoardLetters(): LiveData<List<String>>

    @Query("SELECT boardLettersValue FROM saved_values_table")
    fun readBoardLettersValues (): LiveData<List<Int>>

    @Update
    suspend fun updateValues(values: SavedValues)

    @Query("DELETE FROM saved_values_table")
    suspend fun deleteAllValues()

}
```

My Database:

```
@Database(
    entities = [Word::class, SavedValues::class, SavedWords::class],
    version = 8,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class WordDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun wordDAO(): WordDao
    abstract fun savedValuesDao(): SavedValuesDao
}
```

My Repository:

```
val readAllValues: LiveData<List<SavedValues>> = savedValuesDao.readAllValues()
val readBoardLetters: LiveData<List<String>> = savedValuesDao.readBoardLetters()
val readBoardLettersValues: LiveData<List<Int>> =
    savedValuesDao.readBoardLettersValues()

suspend fun addValues(savedValues: SavedValues) {
    savedValuesDao.addValues(savedValues)
}

suspend fun updateValues(savedValues: SavedValues) {
    savedValuesDao.updateValues(savedValues)
}

suspend fun deleteAllValues() {
    savedValuesDao.deleteAllValues()
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The error is likely in the code you haven't shown...your `readAllValues` StateFlow or LiveData, and how it's created, updated, and subscribed from.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: Well, you were right, the problem was " @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)". I deleted that and it is now fine!

Comment: Could you please post the methods you used in the viewmodel `saveValues()` and `updateValues()`

Comment: Thanks, they are already there, above the update.