# Is it best to use two room databases in this situation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I currently have a prepopulated database with a long list of words. I am using this database to also save some app data in a different table. In this scenario, would it be better to have two separate databases to avoid problems further down the line?

My database currently looks like this:

```
@Database(
    entities = [Word::class, SavedValues::class, SavedWords::class],
    version = 8,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class WordDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun wordDAO(): WordDao
    abstract fun savedValuesDao(): SavedValuesDao
}
```

and my module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideDatabase(
            @ApplicationContext context: Context
        ) = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            WordDatabase::class.java,
            "word_database"
        ).createFromAsset("database/wordlist.db").build()
    
        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideDao(database: WordDatabase) = database.wordDAO()
    
    }
```

When I say "problems further down the line" I mean this specific problem that I explain [here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485915/room-database-update-creates-unexpected-ui-side-effects).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I personally would use two databases if they don’t have anything in common and you don’t need to intersect their tables. Makes it easier to manage their versions independently and do file manipulations with them independently if you ever need to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need two databases, the problems might be because of wrong use of the queries or data management.
Maybe just change your database name to something more generic, like `AppDatabase`, and make sure you are managing the data correctly.